# Where to find people interested in collaborative work between designers and programmers

Tags: designers

What is a good place to find people and make a team to finish projects and perhaps make a profit?

I feel there is this huge disconnection between programmers and designers, and normally there is someone else who acts as a bridge between them. However, both designers and coders have ideas of their own that maybe they can't see completed cause they lack the complete skill set for that task, or the money to hire someone.

Comment: I just solved the problem by learning both graphic design and getting a degree in computer science. Boom.

Comment: I come from a similar background as @OghmaOsiris, started with a computer science degree and migrated to graphic design. I do a little bit of both, not one or the other exclusively. I don't agree that there is a "huge disconnect" between programmers and designers, and I'm not sure how a website would help fix that anyway. As it stands, this question doesn't make much sense, perhaps you could re-word it to add some clarity?

Comment: you could do everything by yourself but that limits to how much you can do while maintaining quality and overlooking much of the necessary stuff.

Comment: @John Also, don't forget that this site has a disproportionately high number of designer/developer hybrids due to the association with stackoverflow.com. Most members of most other design sites won't even know what that site is, whereas here, many of us have active accounts on it. I went the opposite way: learned design then branched out to programming, used stackoverflow, then discovered this site through it. Both backgrounds are unusually common among people on this site, but outside of this site, it's quite rare to have a *good* amount of skills in both areas.

Comment: ...and working with other people has benefits.  ...Although, I usually ask my friends to test functionality of my coding projects as well as ask them some logic and feature related stuff.

Comment: @yisela - I don't think this deserves the `spec-work` tag! This question could be answered by a freelance job board where a programmer shows me his portfolio and tells me he's interested in working on my project. Not sure what I'd tag this though and I didn't want to run up the edit count, so I thought I'd just sound off here :)

Comment: @Brendan You are right. Because the tag doesn't have a description and my English sucks, I thought it was something else! Deleted.

Comment: who made this question so wordy and boring :D

Comment: @OghmaOsiris that's a joke right?

Comment: yea duh...anyhow...i checked out both sites, and 2nd one is more what i am looking for but it is soooo deserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guide google of ["designers developers"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=designers%20developers&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=70f902665fe3d8c&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1357700187,d.cGE&biw=1920&bih=1079) yielded:

- [CollabFinder](http://collabfinder.com) -- Start a project. Build a team.
- [BuildItWith.Me](http://www.builditwith.me/) -- Connecting Designers & Developers